# ibm bluemix node js files

Tags: node.js, git, ibm-cloud

I have an account in IBM Bluemix and when a I try to make a simple node js App, it creates different folders and files like: .git/, launchConfigurations/, .cfignore/, .gitignore/, License.txt and Readme.md, but I can't find the public folder with the index.html file nor the app.js.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a regression in Bluemix. It is now corrected and during the ADD GIT operation, the repo is now populated with the starter code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known issue and is being addressed promptly...

Comment: As a workaround, try downloading the starter code locally and then pushing it manually to the git repo (or import via the Web IDE File -> Import -> Zip or File Archive. If you follow this approach, do not forget to push the files from that IDE to the repo).

Comment: Thank you Randal...

Does this allow me to edit the code with the Web IDE online?
Or do I need to modify locally and then pushing it again?

Comment: You should be able to edit code in the IDE online, as long as you push it back to the repo.  You can also edit locally then push.  Either way should work.